# Adding a dynamic chart in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, charts

I have an asp.net mvc4 application in which i have to add a gantt chart to manage tasks of my project . So i need a tool, component or a library whichi can do with it a chart like :
[the chart](http://www.smartsheet.fr/gestion-de-projets-en-ligne?s=127&c=3&m=3002&a=22313164267&k=gestion%20de%20projet&mtp=e&adp=1t1&net=g&dev=c&devm=&mkwid=s2w0FrWOW&gclid=CJCttNaw_LcCFbMbtAodzkIAAQ)

I found many chart using web forms, but in my case (asp mvc) i didn't found.

So what component can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) a try. Here's the [library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) and [API reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference).

Its totally client side. So has no dependency on webforms or MVC. 
I have used them in my previous project and I have a positive feedback.

Not sure if has gantt chart though.

---

**Other gantt charts that will work for MVC:**

1. http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/chart/ChartType/AdvancedChartType
2. http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm
3. http://mvc.daypilot.org/demo/Scheduler/Gantt

Comment: i didn't find the chart type like in the link